# Recenter Google map in div when div resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Please see my code. When I click the marker, div resized. I want to recenter the map after div gets resized. But it looks like div resize event cannot be captured. (Note: div click event can be captured very well. Don't know why resize event doesn't work.)

I tried below way to recenter map. It didn't work. I appreciate any help.

```
        var currCenter = map.getCenter();
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
        map.setCenter(currCenter);
```

Here is my code:

```
<body>
<div id="map_display"></div>
<script language="JavaScript">

    var map;
    var uluru = {lat: 43.657, lng: -79.384};

    var myicon = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/parking_lot_maps.png';

    function initMap() {

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_display"), {
            center: uluru,
            zoom: 14,
            zoomControl: false
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: uluru,
            map: map,
            title: "bike station",
            icon: myicon
        });

        marker.addListener('click', function () {
            $("#map_display").animate({width: '75%'});
        });
    }

</script>
<script language="JavaScript" async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxxxxxx&callback=initMap"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. trigger the `resize` event on the map after the animation (tells the Google Maps Javascript API the map's size has changed.
2. set the center of the map back to the position of the marker.

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var uluru = {
  lat: 43.657,
  lng: -79.384
};

var myicon = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/parking_lot_maps.png';

function initMap() {

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_display"), {
    center: uluru,
    zoom: 14,
    zoomControl: false
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: uluru,
    map: map,
    title: "bike station",
    icon: myicon
  });

  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    $("#map_display").animate({
      width: '75%'
    }, function() {
      google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
      map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
    });
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_display {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map_display"></div>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"></script>
```